# Detect 30 days (or more) interval between events using event timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: sql, events, timestamp, google-bigquery

I've got a table like this:

```
uid      | eventName | timestamp
------   | ------    | -------
userId1  | login     | 1501839197
userId1  | login     | 1501840142
userId2  | login     | 1503261360
userId2  | login     | 1503261858
userId3  | login     | 1502681803
userId3  | login     | 1502376007
```

The task is to select those uids having more than 30 days between login events. In other words, I need to consistently compare each event's timestamp to a previous one and if the interval >= 30 days, add uid to the result table.

The result table should only contain uids.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I used Standard SQL BigQuery syntax here.

To find that kind of users, you can use **LAG** function ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators)).

```
with data as
(
select uid, timestamp, 
LAG(timestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) as last_login 
from YOUR_TABLE
where eventName = 'login'
)
select uid from data
where TIMESTAMP_DIFF(timestamp, last_login, HOUR) >= (30 * 24)
```

This function allows you to access previous row in order defined by `PARTITION BY` clause. Then you need to select only such rows, for which the difference in days was greater or equal to 30 days (`TIMESTAMP_DIFF` does not have `DAY` support, that's why I used 30*24).

If your *timestamp* column is of type `INT64` then you could use `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()` or `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS()` function to convert number to timestamp in BigQuery ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds)).

Comment: Thanks, Marcin! Looks like it should work. But I forgot one thing. The timestamp column is INTEGER, not TIMESTAMP.

I get this while trying to perform the code

[No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: INT64, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART)]

Should we convert integer to timestamp? If yes, how?

Comment: Marked this answer since it works perfectly when the timestamp column is of timestamp type.